# Kivy child widgets of StackLayout all have pos of (0,0)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

When looping through the children of `StackLayout` which are added dynamically (through a loop), the output of the position of all children is `0,0`. A simple example:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ThisApp(App):

    def build(self):    

        layout = StackLayout(spacing=10,padding=10)

        for i in range(3):
            layout.add_widget(Button(size_hint=(None,None)))
            print(layout.children[i].pos)

        return layout


ThisApp().run()
```

Output:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
```

Why is this? clearly the position of the widgets is not on the bottom left of the window. I don't understand why this is so at all. `StackLayout` is functioning normally and the placement is correct, but somehow the location of the widgets is not registering?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the layouts do not act immediately but when it is necessary, that is when the widgets are being displayed, so we must use a `Clock.schedule_once(...)` calling the function immediately after a frame is displayed.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock

class ThisApp(App):

    def build(self): 

        def callback(dt):
            for i, child in enumerate(self.root.children):
                print(i, child.pos)

        layout = StackLayout(spacing=10,padding=10)
        for i in range(3):
            layout.add_widget(Button(size_hint=(None,None)))
        Clock.schedule_once(callback)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ThisApp().run()
```

Output:

```
0 [230, 370]
1 [120, 370]
2 [10, 370]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for explaining!